# 0 and 1 FROM DUAL Matrix

Tags: oracle, functions, recursive

I need to make a matrix with 0 and 1 combination :

```
SELECT 1 AS F1, 0 AS F2 ,0 AS F3,0 AS F4, 0 AS F5 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 0 AS F1, 1 AS F2 ,0 AS F3,0 AS F4, 0 AS F5 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 0 AS F1, 0 AS F2 ,1 AS F3,0 AS F4, 0 AS F5 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 0 AS F1, 0 AS F2 ,0 AS F3,1 AS F4, 0 AS F5 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 0 AS F1, 0 AS F2 ,0 AS F3,0 AS F4, 1 AS F5 FROM DUAL
```

Do you have some code more tricky or elegant to achieve this ?

I'm on Oracle 19c

Thx

Comment: If you want to Name the columns it is Sufficient to do this in the first select

Comment: @miracle173 yes absolutely, it's was here just a lazy copy/paste ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three more methods, one that uses the function `SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST()` and `TABLE()` to produce a 5-rows table, a second that uses `CONNECT BY` (Oracle's old method for recursive queries) and a third that abuses `GROUPING SETS`.

Note that `TABLE()` is not needed in recent versions. In the first query, we could just use:

```
from SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) ;
```

---

Tested in [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/HMWbzWu1):

```
select * from V$VERSION;
```

| BANNER | BANNER_FULL | BANNER_LEGACY | CON_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Oracle Database 21c Express Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production | Oracle Database 21c Express Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production Version 21.3.0.0.0 | Oracle Database 21c Express Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production | 0 |

```
select  
  case when column_value  = 1 then 1 else 0 end as f1,  
  case when column_value  = 2 then 1 else 0 end as f2,
  case when column_value  = 3 then 1 else 0 end as f3,
  case when column_value  = 4 then 1 else 0 end as f4,
  case when column_value  = 5 then 1 else 0 end as f5
from table(
  SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
) ;
```

| F1 | F2 | F3 | F4 | F5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

```
select case when rownum = 1 then 1 else 0 end as F1
     , case when rownum = 2 then 1 else 0 end as F2
     , case when rownum = 3 then 1 else 0 end as F3
     , case when rownum = 4 then 1 else 0 end as F4
     , case when rownum = 5 then 1 else 0 end as F5
from  dual
  connect by level <= 5 ;
```

| F1 | F2 | F3 | F4 | F5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

```
select case when rownum = 1 then 1 else 0 end as F1
     , case when rownum = 2 then 1 else 0 end as F2
     , case when rownum = 3 then 1 else 0 end as F3
     , case when rownum = 4 then 1 else 0 end as F4
     , case when rownum = 5 then 1 else 0 end as F5
from 
  ( select count(*) from dual
    group by grouping sets
      ((), (), (), (), ())  -- 5 groupings
  ) t ;
```

| F1 | F2 | F3 | F4 | F5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HMWbzWu1)

Comment: thanks for sharing ! never heard about those ODCI% array,  I will take a look at Oracle's documentation ^^

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating the combinations your self, you can let the DB do it for you:

```
with d(x) as ( select 0 from dual union all select 1 from dual )
select d1.x as F1
     , d2.x as F2
     , d3.x as F3
     , d4.x as F4
     , d5.x as F5 
from d d1
cross join d d2
cross join d d3
cross join d d4
cross join d d5;
```

EDIT: misread your question

```
with d(x) as ( select 0 from dual union all select 1 from dual )
select case when rownum = 1 then 1 else 0 end as F1
     , case when rownum = 2 then 1 else 0 end as F2
     , case when rownum = 3 then 1 else 0 end as F3
     , case when rownum = 4 then 1 else 0 end as F4
     , case when rownum = 5 then 1 else 0 end as F5
from d d1
cross join d d2
cross join d d3
order by rownum  
fetch first 5 rows only
;
```

Instead of cross joining a table with 2 rows, it is also possible to use group by cube:

```
with d(x) as ( select 0 from dual group by cube(1,1,1) )
select case when rownum = 1 then 1 else 0 end as F1
     , case when rownum = 2 then 1 else 0 end as F2
     , case when rownum = 3 then 1 else 0 end as F3
     , case when rownum = 4 then 1 else 0 end as F4
     , case when rownum = 5 then 1 else 0 end as F5
from d d1
order by rownum  
fetch first 5 rows only
;
```

Comment: thx for this one !